# JW-PLAYER : load video 3rd instead of 1st video from playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

With this below code. i want to do something different.

When the page will load i want to load video "**xyz.mp4**" instead first "**sintel.mp4**". means the video playing should start from 3rd video instead of 1st video which are set in playlist in below code..

[JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player) link here.

If anyone familer with this JWPLAYER then please give me solution.

**Question : how could i do this ? What advancement needed ?**

**Code**

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    playlist: [{
    image: "/assets/sintel.jpg",
    file: "/assets/sintel.mp4",
    title: "Sintel Movie Trailer"
    },{
    image: "/assets/bunny.jpg",
    file: "/assets/bunny.mp4",
    title: "Big Buck Bunny Movie Trailer"
    },{
    image: "/assets/xyz.jpg",
    file: "/assets/xyz.mp4",
    title: "test xyz video."
    },{
    image: "/assets/abc.jpg",
    file: "/assets/abc.mp4",
    title: "abc video."
    },{
    image: "/assets/tuv.jpg",
    file: "/assets/tuv.mp4",
    title: "TUV video"
    }]
    });
```

Thank you.

**Update :**

problem is little bit solved with **[playlistItem(index)](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/)** as answered by [Spokey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2220391/spokey) . 
but the video should not start play. i need just load not start. means no playback only load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "/assets/sintel.jpg",
        file: "/assets/sintel.mp4",
        title: "Sintel Movie Trailer"
    }, {
        image: "/assets/bunny.jpg",
        file: "/assets/bunny.mp4",
        title: "Big Buck Bunny Movie Trailer"
    }, {
        image: "/assets/xyz.jpg",
        file: "/assets/xyz.mp4",
        title: "test xyz video."
    }, {
        image: "/assets/abc.jpg",
        file: "/assets/abc.mp4",
        title: "abc video."
    }, {
        image: "/assets/tuv.jpg",
        file: "/assets/tuv.mp4",
        title: "TUV video"
    }]
}).playlistItem(2).stop(); // index of the video
```

Found at http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/

Comment: great where was my dead mind.. :) i will try and will tick as a right ans. thankx again

Comment: problem is little bit solved, the video should not start playback. i need just load. not start. means no playback only load.

Comment: @JohnHarper `.playlistItem(2).stop()` ?

Comment: Just add jwplayer().play();